# Parsing a yaml file with Golang

Tags: parsing, go, yaml

I'm trying to parse a `yaml` file with Golang. I defined the following `types`:

```
type DockerNetwork struct {
   MyNetwork struct {
      driver string
   } `yaml:"my_network"`
}

// DockerNetworks represent the docker Networks type
type DockerNetworks struct {
    networks []DockerNetwork
}
```

so I have my unit test in place:

```
func TestDockerNetwork(t *testing.T) {
    dn := DockerNetworks{}
    var data = `
networks:
   my_network:
     driver: bridge
    `
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &dn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
        t.Error("Could not Unmarshal the data")
    }
    log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("--- t:\n%v\n\n", dn))
}
```

I expected it to work, however I'm getting no input:

```
2016/12/14 13:38:12 --- t:
{{}}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is unclear in the error message? Your YAML is a map and maps cannot be unmarshaled to a slice. So maybe use a map?

Comment: @Volker let me reformulate my question...

Comment: @Volker I've updated my question

Comment: You have unexported fields in your structs, and you still only have mappings in your yaml.

Comment: You have to write `networks` and `driver` fields with the first letter as upper case, to make them public

Answer (score 2):

My `yaml` file is a `docker-compose.yml` file, which is in the format described above (part of it). I agree with Marius that I have unexported fields, which is an error. The solution I used was `map`:

```
m := make(map[interface{}]interface{})

err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
if err != nil {
   log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
}
fmt.Printf("--- m:\n%v\n\n", m)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIKT there to things, data structures with unexported fields and test data which doesn't match your data structures.

Something like this would give you a go:

```
type DockerNetwork struct {
    MyNetwork struct {
        Driver string `yaml:driver`
    } `yaml:"my_network"`
}

type DockerNetworks struct {
    Networks []DockerNetwork `yaml:networks`
}
```

And test data:

```
networks:
-  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Gives an output:

```
2016/12/14 23:47:23 --- t:
{[{{bridge}}]}


PASS
```

And It's hard to tell, what is "working" in your opinion.

Comment: Marius, the main issue here is that output comes from a `docker-compose.yml` file, which will be parsed and used alongside the docker go API. The docker-compose output does not have that format. I solved the issue by using maps.